# Count number of failed grades SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the top 5 students with the most failed grades. So I have to count the number of failed grades for each `PERSON_ID`, and then I need to order it by the number of failed grades for each `PERSON_ID` and then top

With this statement all of the tables are joined and only the students with failed grades are shown. Now I just need to count the number of failed grades for each `PERSON_ID` and then order it.

I keep getting syntax errors when I do this. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting? You need to qualify person_id as I describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify person_id by making it students.person_id since you have that column in multiple tables

```
select top 5 * from (
Select students.person_id, enroll_period, count(*) cnt from students 
inner join grades on students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID 
inner join grade_types on grades.Grade = grade_types.Grade
Where PASSING_GRADE = 0
group by students.person_id, enroll_period)a
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: See updated and please upvote and accept answer if it works for you -thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use something like below query.
I would be careful with count in joins specially when I don't know more about the columns/schema/data

```
Select 
TOP 5
    students.PERSON_ID, 
    NumberOfGradesFailed=COUNT(1) 
from students 
    inner join grades 
        on students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID 
    inner join grade_types 
        on grades.Grade = grade_types.Grade
where PASSING_GRADE = 0
group by students.PERSON_ID 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```